Is it possible to conditionnaly apply mapping modifier based on condition
It would be nice if we - for instance - would like to require fields such as:
type TestKey<T, K extends keyof T> = K extends 'b' ? true : false

type RequiredIf<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: TestKey<T, K> extends true ? T[P]-? : T[P]
                // ^no modifier here                 ^^ applying modifier here
}

type test = RequiredIf<{a: 1, b?: 2, c?: 3}> // {a: 1, b: 2, c?: 3}

This is illegal but is they're a way to achieve this ? Would it make sens to open a request feature for such a feature ?
I would love to be able to write mapping modifier on the type level.

No, this is not possible, you need to simulate it by writing multiple mapped types and intersecting them. I'm sure I've done this before, let me find a duplicate.

Would it make sens to open a request feature for it as it appears to be quite clean code to achieve this

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32562 is the request.

This approach is how I'd do it. There are more awful hoops you can jump through if you require the resulting type to be a single object type with the properties in the same order as the original, but the intersection is equivalent and I won't belabor the point here.

Thank you very much and I know how to render it in just one object
